# Using Laravel Query Builder returns Undefined property: stdClass error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a query that works before using laravel eloquent method

```
$products = Product::where('category', 'ILIKE', '%'.$conditionTxt.'%')
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            ->get();
```

But after using query builder approach

```
$products = DB::table('products')
                      ->where('category', 'ILIKE', '%'.$conditionTxt.'%')
                      ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                      ->get();
```

It returns this error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$inventory

Here is my model and portion of the view where it points the error.

**Model**

```
public function inventory(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\InventoryRecord\InventoryRecord');
}
```

**View:**

```
<td>
    <?php 
    for($i = 0; $i < count($val->inventory); $i++){
        if( $val->inventory[$i]->total_qty <= 50 )  { ?>
            <span style="color:#C00"><?php echo $val->inventory[$i]->total_qty.' -'; ?></span>
        <?php  }else{ ?>
            <span style="color:#25A602"><?php echo $val->inventory[$i]->total_qty.' -'; ?></span>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Can somebody help me with this please? :(

Answer (score 1):

When you use query builder approach it returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` containing the results where each result is an instance of the **PHP `StdClass` object** (not a model object). You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a property of the object.

But you can't access the Model relations because you have PHP `StdClass` object.

I would suggest you, stick to Laravel `eloquent`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two different pieces of functionality. Laravel provides a data access layer, which is the Query Builder. Laravel also provides an ORM called Eloquent, which is built on top of the Query Builder.

When you use Eloquent to query the database, you will get instances of your Eloquent Models back.

When you use the Query Builder to query the database, you will get instances of `stdClass` back.

The query builder doesn't, and shouldn't, know anything about your Eloquent models. If you need Eloquent functionality (like accessing your `inventory` relationship), then you need to use Eloquent to query the database.